# only display plugin if on homepage using wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an image slider plugin and i use this in my PHP header (header.php) to display it only on the homepage

```
<?php putRevSlider("home", "homepage") ?>
```

I want to display spaces/line breaks above and below the slider but only if on the homepage. i tried doing:

```
<?php
if( is_home() ) : ?>
    <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
    <?php putRevSlider("home", "homepage") ?>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

but that does not display anything

Comment: Do you have a static front page set in the Dashboard or is this the Blogroll? If home is a static front page you have to use the is_front_page() conditional instead of is_home() that works for the blog index.

Comment: Revolution Slider is a premium plugin. You should discuss that [on the plugin's support page](http://codecanyon.net/item/slider-revolution-responsive-wordpress-plugin/2751380/support)

Answer (score 3):

Use `is_front_page()` instead of `is_home()` - this ensures you are on the actual 'front page' instead of the 'home page' (which defaults to the blog posts page, index.php).

Answer (score 1):

Check if your Theme apply a class to the wrapper container and solve this via css ( usually a standard )

with the class .home tag

and add padding to

```
.home .slider_container { padding:20px 0 0 20px }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom home page, you can experience difficulties with `is_home()`

Try getting the `post_id` and matching it against the wp_option `get_option('page_on_front')`

```
<?php
global $post;
if( get_option( 'page_on_front' ) == $post->ID : ?>
    <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
    <?php putRevSlider("home", "homepage") ?>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```